# jQuery remembering if a script was already injected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

**Update: It's not really necessary to remove added scripts considering once they run you can't really erase or delete all of the effect they've had on the page.**

This is going to confuse a lot of poeple so sit back, relax, and grab some coffee.  Really try hard to understand this.

First I'm going to explain what I'm doing.

1.)  Ajax requests data from php using specific ID.
2.)  PHP responds with a script from the specific ID.
3.)  Javascript injects those returned scripts into dom for the purpose of running.

What I need help  with:  I want to ensure the same script doesn't get injected twice.  So I could use the url and somehow store that value somewhere.  Then the javascript could check to see if that a script was already executed, and not run it.

Note: Don't recommend jQuery.getscript(); or anything like that.

```
xhr = jQuery.ajax({ url: 'getscript.php?id=something', dateType: 'json', method: 'GET', async:false});

xhr.success(function(json){

     if(json.script) {                  
            var script   = document.createElement("script");
            script.type  = "text/javascript";
            script.text   = json.script;
            document.body.appendChild(script);

            // remove from the dom
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild);
            delete UnusedReferencedObjects;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an id on the script block you created you should simply be able to query against if the id is present on the dom.

Your ajax call would look like this.

```
var theId = "something";
xhr = jQuery.ajax({ url: 'getscript.php?id=' + theId, dateType: 'json', method: 'GET', async:false});

xhr.success(function(json){

     if(json.script && $('#'+theId).length == 0) {                  
            var script   = document.createElement("script");
            script.type  = "text/javascript";
            script.text   = json.script;
            script.id = theId;
            document.body.appendChild(script);

            // remove from the dom
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild);
            delete UnusedReferencedObjects;
      }
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Nhg8y/).

Comment: This is good, but I don't see in your code where you actually assigned that ID to the script.  Like script.id = url;

Comment: Nm in your jsfiddle.net example you did, I was looking at the one in your post.

Comment: Also there is another issue, if your url contains these (. ? =) so for example if your url is (get.script.php?i=5&s=sripts)  then your script fails.  Shown here, http://jsfiddle.net/Y5n4v/.  I guess you would have to use regex to strip out the (. ? =) but thats so hard on the browser to do that everytime, any suggestions to combat this?

Comment: How is the url generated?  Any chance you could use your `i=` and `s=` values to generate the id instead of relying on the full url for the id?

Answer (score 2):

Just store a list of all script IDs that have been executed, and check against it every time you are about to execute a new script in your success function.

Comment: My problem is figuring out the best way to store the urls like.  I don't know if I should use jQuery.data(); or attach them to the actual element.

Comment: You can bind a list object to the "this" object inside the callback function by doing `.success($.proxy(callback_func() {..}, loaded_scripts_array));`, then check if `this[id]` is set inside the callback function before executing.